# Export dynamic number of Access tables to Excel

Tags: excel, export, ms-access-2016

I am trying to export multiple Access tables to Excel.

It works if I nominate the tables and RS1 etc., but I need to do this as a dynamic number of Access tables into one Excel report. (This is a weekly customer report and can vary from week to week, but need the export to be in one report, not multiple Excel exports.)

The following works.

```
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset,
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
```

The below returns an error.

```
Dim rs() As DAO.Recordset
```

I have a counter that can count every time the Access table changes, but the RS part now shows an error.

```
myRowCount = 1            
Set rs(myRowCount) = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(mycustomers, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array:

```vb
Dim Recordsets()    As DAO.Recordset
Dim Index           As Integer

ReDim Recordsets(1 To 3)

Set Recordsets(1) = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Customer")
Set Recordsets(2) = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Client")
Set Recordsets(3) = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Contact")

For Index = LBound(Recordsets) To UBound(Recordsets)
    Debug.Print Index, Recordsets(Index).RecordCount
    Recordsets(Index).Close
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav, i can update some of my report like this.  is there a way to set the number of Recordset to the number of customer in the tbl_customer table.  This week i could have 10 customers, next week could be 20 etc.  I have to put them all in 1 excel report.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but read the _RecordCount_ of the customer recordset and adjust what is needed.

Comment: i got this to work.           ReDim Recordsets(1 To ourRecordset.RecordCount)

For I = 1 To ourRecordset.RecordCount
Set Recordsets(I) = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(myCustomers)
                    
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets.Add
With xlSheet
           .Name = myCustomers
For cols = 0 To Recordsets(I).Fields.Count 
          .Cells(1, cols + 1).Value = Recordsets(I).Fields(cols).Name
  Next
         .Cells(1, cols + 1).Font.Name = "Calibri"
         .Cells(1, cols + 1).Font.Size = 10
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset Recordsets(I
End With
  ourRecordset.MoveNext
Next I

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction Gustav

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered if you feel so.